# Setting data into JSON file

Tags: reactjs, json, database

Is it not possible to store data to JSON file ? I mean I want to store the questions from the UI. I haven't started my database concepts yet. I know it is far far efficient to use Database.

Can anyone tell me if it is not at all possible.

Thank you

I just now studied how to get data and it worked. But when i tried to search for storing data I wasn't getting any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a React.js application, you can store data in a JSON file. You can read the JSON file using the `fetch` API or any other method, parse its contents, and then use the data within your React components.

Here's an example of how you can read data from a JSON file in a React component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('questions.json');
        const data = await response.json();
        setQuestions(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Questions</h1>
      <ul>
        {questions.map(question => (
          <li key={question.id}>{question.question}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Also I recommend using json-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server )

Check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can make a data.json with data for each api and run that json file  in a server using command called npm run json:server

Add in package.json under scripts
"json:server":"json-server --watch  --port "

Then run npm run json:server server will run

After that you can call the data such as calling to API sample API will be http://localhost/getNames

You can add more data and run again too